# how to properly set up a database config file for sequelize? i keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'max')"

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js, development-environment, sequelize-cli

basically, i am trying to make my app choose which database it's going to use. i'm having trouble, because i keep getting a "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'max')". i've spent about three hours on this (*very* new to web stack stuff, so don't laugh at me please) and could **really** use some assistance. thanks in advance.

db.config.js.

it doesn't work with pool active either, so don't mind that.

```
require('dotenv').config();


module.exports = {
  dev: {
    HOST: "localhost",
    USER: "postgres",
    PASSWORD: "redacted",
    DB: "testtest",
    //dialect: "mysql"
    dialect: "postgres"
  }, // pool was here, removed it to make the whole thing smaller 
  production:{
    // empty until i get actual production values from my hosting service 
  }
}
```

index.js

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev';
const config = require("../config/db.config.js");

const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.DB,
  config.USER,
  config.PASSWORD,
  {
    host: config.HOST,
    dialect: config.dialect,
    operatorsAliases: false,

    pool: {
      // omitted to make example smaller 
    }
  }
);

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

// ...models relationships defined here 

module.exports = db;
```

to my understanding,

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev';
```

means that if a value isn't present within my .env file (it isn't), it will default to 'dev' settings, and connect to my local database.

```
const config = require("../config/db.config.js");
```

this is here so the file can access those values.

i tried making an entirely separate file for environment configuration, but it gave me a sequelize error (that i can't pull up right now). this is what i had before:

```
const dbEngine = process.env.DB_ENVIRONMENT || 'dev';
const config = require('./db.config')[dbEngine];

module.exports = require('sequelize')(config);
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Bumping this! I'm trying to move on to other features; this is still stymieing me.